# Scala/ Intellij - conditional breakpoint in primary constructor?

Tags: scala, debugging, intellij-idea

How do I put a conditional breakpoint inside the primary constructor of a Scala class using Idea's IntelliJ?

Comment: Like any other breakpoint. If you have a problem, share the code example and specify what exactly doesn't work for you.

Comment: How does it differ from a class loading breakpoint? Since you're working for Idea, could you make this obvious like in Eclipse instead of voting my question down prematurely?

Comment: I did not downvote your question.

Answer (score 0):

Should be easy.

- **click on the left edge of the line** you want to put breakpoint on. Once you click, shows a red bubble.
- **Or** put the cursor on the line you want to put breakpoint on, and then goto `Run -> Toggle Line Breakpoint`
- **Or** you can put the cursor on the line you want to put breakpoint on and use shortcut, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd>

see the screen shots below,

**1) while using param constructor**
[image: default const]

**2) using empty constructor**
[image: change const]

For more -

[Creating Line Breakpoints](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/creating-line-breakpoints.html)

[How to Debug Java with IntelliJ: Breakpoints, Evaluate Expression, Watches, and Variable View](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-debug-java-with-intellij-breakpoints-evalua)

Comment: thanks for your answer. It still doesn't allow me to stop on a condition